# Releasing Cache from an Active Python Script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to scrape a site and write the data in a txt file.

However, when I run the script, the system memory used by Python gets larger and larger as it proceeds.

To an extent that it even exceeds 1Gb of used memory and almost freeze down my system.
After a span of 8 hours.

Is there a way, I could release the cache or temporary data the script is holding to make it lighter.
Or may be restart the script automatically from where it stopped?
Or same way to release the amount of memory that it occupies with time and let it run for hours without freezing my system?

Could someone please advise. Thank you.

Comment: We can't suggest anything, unless you show us your code.

Comment: Well try to profile your script. You must be leaving some objects that are not getting garbage collected. May be there is something that you can manually clean in your script to reduce mem usage. Sadly nobody will be able to help much without seeing your code. So I suggest that you watch this talk from PyCon 2014 which tells you a lot about memory profiling in Python: http://pyvideo.org/video/2698/track-memory-leaks-in-python. This should help you tons.

Comment: Those were the print commands that were increasing the cache and hence the system memory.
Thanks vaidik, your comment helped me solve this.

If you can please post an answer, I will accept it as the right one. Thanks again